# shared_children not working in Capistrano 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I have the following in my `deploy.rb`:

```
set :upload_dirs, %w(public/pictures)
set :shared_children, (fetch(:shared_children) || []) + fetch(:upload_dirs)
```

This seems to be the suggested method to allow me to have the public directory shared.

The `public/pictures` directory exists and is checked in empty in the repository. I tried to also not have it in the repository but it didn't work anyway.

When I deploy with capistrano, I don't see the `public/pictures` directory appearing anywhere in my deploy location.

Has this feature been removed from Capistrano 3? 
Is there a definitive source of documentation for Capistrano 3? All I can find is Capistrano 2 documentation and very scarce sources of information for v3.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This seems to be an undocumented change from Capistrano 2 to 3. In the new version, the name seems to be `:linked_dirs`.

I updated my code as such:

```
set :linked_files, %w(config/database.yml config/application.yml)
set :linked_dirs, %w(public/pictures)
```

I also took the chance to use the new `:linked_files` feature, which allows you to link files found in the `shared` directory directly into your `current` application without having to write custom tasks for it.

Both variables seem to be `nil` at first, so you don't have to fetch the current value to append your own directories to them.

Comment: Thanks for this. You can also use `append` instead of `set` to ensure you aren't overwriting anything.